# Getting the following error while capistrano deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

Getting the following error while deploying

```
DEBUG[c3b88189] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home/ubuntu/apps/stag/shared/config/database.yml ] on **.***.***.**
DEBUG[c3b88189] Command: [ -f /home/ubuntu/apps/
stag/shared/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG[c3b88189] Finished in 0.579 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
ERROR linked file /home/ubuntu/apps/stag/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on **.***.***.**
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host **.***.***.**: exit

SystemExit: exit

Tasks: TOP => deploy:check:linked_files
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host
```

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

The remote_file task is allowing the existence of a remote file to be set as a prerequisite. These tasks can in turn depend on local files if required.

```
namespace :deploy do
  namespace :check do
    task :linked_files => 'config/database.yml'
  end
end

remote_file 'config/database.yml' => '/local/database.yml'
```

http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/remote-file/